# Arduino Traffic Lights and LCD

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, lcd

I have created a simple traffic lights situation with an LCD screen. The countdown time is set as 60 seconds in "Adruino for LCD", and I wish the traffic light runs normally at 59 to 11 seconds when it is counting down. Then,  I hope all traffic lights turn **to red from green** when it shows the countdown at **10 to 0** second.

Here is the screenshot of my Arduino circuit.
[image: Screenshot of Arduino Circuit]

Original code for Traffic Lights:

```
void loop() { 
  
    //   road - 1
 
    // green signal for the first road 
  
    digitalWrite(g1, HIGH);
  
    digitalWrite(r2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(r3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(r4, HIGH);
  
  
    // delay time for red signal - 9 seconds
    delay(10000);
  
    // cosing first road  
    digitalWrite(g1, LOW);
  
    // yello signal for first and scond road (3 seconds)
    digitalWrite(r2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(y1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(y2, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
  
    // green signal for second road and disable yellow signals
    digitalWrite(y1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(y2, LOW);
  
    //   road - 2
    ...

    //   road - 3
    ...

    //   road - 4
    ...

}
```

I tried to add for loop for traffic lights.

```
for (int seconds = 60; seconds >= 11; seconds--)

{
 
    //road 1
    digitalWrite(g1, HIGH);
        :
        :

    //road 4


if(seconds==11){
    for (int j = 10; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        //road 1
            digitalWrite(r1, HIGH);

            :
            :

         //road 4
    }
}
}
```

but it doesn't for the second condition, as I want all the traffic lights should turn to red when it counts from 10 to 0.

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch, I tried to add for loop for traffic lights. 

`for (int seconds = 60; seconds >= 11; seconds--)`
`{`
 `//road 1`
 `digitalWrite(**g1**, HIGH);`
  
    `:`
    `:`
 
 `//road 4`
 
 
 `if(seconds==11){`
  `for (int j = 10; j >= 0; j--)`
  `{`
 
   `//road 1`
            `digitalWrite(**r1**, HIGH);`
  
            `:`
            `:`
 
      ` //road 4`
        `}`
    `}`
`}`

but it doesn't for the second condition, as I want all the traffic lights should turn to red when it counts from 10 to 0.

Comment: You just learned that comments are not good for showing details. Please [edit] the question. Have a look at [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch, I have tried to edit my question and hope it is clear now. Really thanks a lot as I am still not familiar with stack overflow too.  Appreciate what you have shared with me.